# Proof of equivalent probabilities in anomaly detection

Tags: probability, statistics

In *A New Look at Anomaly Detection* there is a claim for the proof of probabilistic definition of normal  is as follows,

a guess of the probability for event i is $\pi_i$, the true probability is $p_i$ then "if we make the average value of $-\log \pi_i$ as small as possible then we can prove the estimated probabilities are as close as possible to the underlying $p_i$" (direct quote)

in particular that
$\max_{\pi} \sum_i{p_i\log{\pi_i}}=\sum_i{p_i\log{p_i}}$

I don't follow the logic of why this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any $\pi\in (0,1)^I$ with $\sum_{i\in I}\pi_i=1$. Then

$$\sum_{i\in I} p_i\ln p_i-\sum_{i\in I} p_i\ln \pi_i=-\sum_{i\in I} p_i\ln \frac{\pi_i}{p_i}$$
$$\ge -\sum_{i\in I} p_i\ln \frac{\pi_i}{p_i}\ge -\ln\left[\sum_{i\in I} p_i\frac{\pi_i}{p_i}\right]=-\ln\left[\sum_{i\in I}\pi_i\right]=0$$

This inequality shows that

$$\max_{\pi} \sum_{i\in I}{p_i\log{\pi_i}}=\sum_{i\in I}{p_i\log{p_i}}$$

Actually, the quantity $\sum_{i\in I} p_i\ln \frac{p_i}{\pi_i}$ is the the *Kullback–Leibler divergence* which measures the difference between $p$ and $\pi$. Small $KLIC$ means that $\pi$ is "close" to the true distribution $p$.

Comment: Some minor notation questions, what does the max over pi actually mean in this context? Also what does the raised to the I impy in the set that pi is an element of?

Comment: Max over all possible distributions $(\pi_1, \pi_2,\dots)$ s.t. $\sum \pi_i=1$